# Dart Webdev Dev Compiler not running since upgrade to 2.3.2

Tags: dart, dart-dev-compiler

Since I have moved from Dart 2.1.0 to 2.3.2 "webdev serve" runs successfully, but when I run the project, it gets a 404 on "main.digests". I updated my dev dependencies of build_runner, build_web_compiler, and webdev to the latest versions, and the issue still occurs.

It still builds in dart2js fine. Even if it is "webdev serve --release" it works.

Here is a copy of my pubspec:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.3.2 <3.0.0'
dependencies:
  analyzer: any
  intl: any
  stagexl: 1.4.0+2
  stagexl_particle: ^0.4.0
  uuid: ^1.0.3
dependency_overrides:
  stagexl:
    git: https://github.com/AndrewLugg/StageXL.git
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.6.1
  build_web_compilers: ^2.1.1
  webdev: ^2.2.0
```

and here is my build.yaml

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      build_web_compilers|entrypoint:
        generate_for:
        - web/app/**.dart
        options:
          dart2js_args:
          - --fast-startup
          - --no-source-maps
          - --show-package-warnings
          - --trust-primitives
          - --trust-type-annotations
          - --omit-implicit-checks
```

Here is a copy of the error:

```
http://localhost:53322/webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js:2693
GET http://localhost:53322/app/main.digests 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught Instance of 'minified:b0'      client.js:367
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem disappeared once we upgraded to Dart SDK 2.5.2, there was no real explanation to why this happened.